# simple comment code won't collaborate with notification app

Tags: python, django

my code for comment works fine but as soon as I add notification feature it doesn't work, while notification kinda works. I'm using django-notification-hq 3rd party app. from here: https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications

here's my code

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_edit', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_delete', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        notify.send(self.author, recipient=self.post.author, action_object=self.post, target=self, verb="commented on")
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def comment_new(request, post_pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect(comment.post)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'community/comment_form.html', {
        'form':form,
        })
```

urls.py

```
 path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/new',views.comment_new, name='comment_new'),
```

I added this single line,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            notify.send(self.author, recipient=self.post.author, action_object=self.post, target=self, verb="commented on")
```

My new model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_edit', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_delete', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            notify.send(self.author, 
                        recipient=self.post.author, 
                        action_object=self.post, 
                        target=self, 
                        verb="commented on")

        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    error message: NameError: name 'Comment' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the save-method on the model, you need to pass the arguments to `super()` afterwards to maintain the primary behaviour. The below code should make it work as before:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    notify.send(self.author, 
                recipient=self.post.author, 
                action_object=self.post, 
                target=self, 
                verb="commented on")

    super(Class, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

try this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_edit', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_delete', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        notify.send(self.author, 
                    recipient=self.post.author, 
                    action_object=self.post, 
                    target=self, 
                    verb="commented on")

        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i get NameError: name 'Comment' is not defined

Comment: Try to leave the parenthesis in `super()` blank. I have edited my answer now

Comment: what argument is suppose to be in super()?

Comment: I had an indentation-error in my code-sample, in case you copy/pasted. If you did, you can try again now

Comment: `super()` doesn't really need arguments anymore, but the old convention was to use the Class name + an object instance, which would result in your case to be `super(Comment, self)`

Comment: no indentation isn't the problem, it says RuntimeError: super(): no arguments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194448/discussion-between-rosababy-and-kent-martin).

Answer (score 1):

You've added custom logic in a `save` handler, but without a `super` call you've completely overridden the base `save` logic.

Your problem statement is too vague to be sure, but I imagine adding `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` in your custom `save` method will solve whatever problem you're having.

Comment: I added def super().save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  notify.send(self.author, recipient=self.post.author, action_object=self.post, target=self, verb="commented on") but it says SyntaxError: invalid syntax (models.py, line 82)

Comment: You don't need to define the super call. Add the line `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` before or after the `notify.send` line in your save method, at the same indentation level as the `notify.send` line.

Comment: what argument is supposed to be in super()?

Comment: hi can you please join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194448/discussion-between-rosababy-and-kent-martin

Comment: Respectfully, you've gotten good help from two users here already. Your edit contains an indentation error. Please re-read my previous comment and notice that your `notify.send` line and `super` call are on different indentation levels. Again, respectfully, you need to clean up your code and digest the information you've been provided before requesting further help.

Comment: okay but where's Comment from? why does it say name 'comment is not defined;